# I always get the last onload function, but I need both, Is there any other alternate option without removing any of window.onload event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I always get the last `onload` function, but I need both, Is there any other alternate option without removing any of `window.onload` event?

```
window.onload = function(){
    alert("first");
}

window.onload = function(){
    alert("second");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When declaring the second one, you can chain with the first.

```
var lastOnLoad = window.onload;
window.onload = function(){
    lastOnLoad();
    alert("second");
}
```

You also can make an utility like this :

```
function addOnLoad(f) {
    var lastOnLoad = window.onload;
    window.onload = function() {
        lastOnLoad();
        f();
    }
}
```

You'd call it like this :

```
addOnLoad(function(){
    alert("first");
});

addOnLoad(function(){
    alert("second");
});
```

EDIT : or you may simply do what ThiefMaster suggests... (I'll upvote him !).

Comment: While this works it will "break" as soon as another script simply assigns to `window.onload` without properly calling the previous handler.

Comment: This wouldn't really "break" : this would do what "window.onload=" means. But you're right that your answer is simpler and better ;)

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be registering the event listener using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) instead of assigning it to `window.onload`:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    // your code
}, false);
```

You can do this multiple times and it will never overwrite previous listeners.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    alert("first");
}, false)

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    alert("second");
}, false)
```